# Is there a shotcut to recent files?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I use a small program in Windows so I can see recent files (when I save downloaded files and then need to send them by email) and it's super useful.
Is there something like that on Ubuntu?
Thank you!

Comment: I chuckle, remembering all the turn-of-the-century internet arguments about how evil MS was by tracking user actions with MRUs, and about how Gnome and KDE respected user privacy by not doing the same. I'm sure that's not entirely true nowadays, but i did enjoy the irony.

Comment: Thank you all. What I was looking for is a way to have something as RecentX so I can quicly find my recent files.
https://www.conceptworld.com/RecentX/download

I know I can find it with Files in Ubuntu but I was looking for something easier.
Does anyone has an Idea or maybe there is a software as RecentX for Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Do you mean if there's a way to do this on the CLI, or are you using the GUI and a file browser?

For example here's how to add "Recent files" to Thunar's side panel:

1. Open ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks with your text editor.
2. Add this line at the end: recent:/
3. Save the file.
4. Open thunar. There should be a recent bookmark on the side panel now

Courtesy of user @Laurentius in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392882/can-i-add-recent-items-view-to-thunar-bookmarks

According to a quick web search Dolphin and Nautilus at least had Recent Items list available by default. I just googled for "dolphin recent items" and "nautilus recent items", without quotes.

EDIT

I just tested the Thunar instruction on Bunsenlabs Lithium (Debian 10) & Thunar 1.8.4. Even if I manage my files on CLI, Thunar sidebar now indeed has an entry "Recent" which contains the list of files I've accessed using the graphical applications like LiberOffice Impress, Archive Manager or packet manager.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the GUI you are using. For example GNOME Flashback, the "old style" GNOME desktop (which I'm using), has a "Recently used documents" entry in the "Places" menu.

Also Nautilus, GNOME's default file manager, has a "Recently used" entry in the sidebar menu.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has no such shortcuts, but you can build them yourself.

Listing today's modified files in the current folder using the
[**ls command**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

```
ls  -al --time-style=+%D | grep `date +%D`
```

where:

- `-a` : list all files including hidden files
- `-l` : enables long listing format
- `--time-style=FORMAT` : shows time in the specified FORMAT
- `+%D` : show/use date in `%m/%d/%y` format

Or using the
[**find command**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "2021-09-05"
```

You will find more command options in the `man` pages.